# Parsing the successful response of Backbone.create method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

The api's I work with return an object like

```
{
  status:'success',
  data: [{
    id: '37r878',
    desc: 'foo',
    summary: 'bar',
    ts: 00000000,
    status: 'open'
  }],
  message: null
}
```

When I run the `create()` method in backbone I am passing it an object 
example

```
{
  desc: 'foo',
  summary: 'bar',
  ts: 00000000,
  status: 'new'
}
```

which triggers a POST expectedly to create the new data. The issue is, that when the API responds with the object I show up top, amd is added to what data I created the model with (shown below), as well as in the case of the **status** property it gets overwritten, by the responses value.

What I am trying to figure out is how to I bypass this automatic updating of the model with the response, or better yet how do I update it specifically with the responses **data** property instead of the whole response.

So my Model ends up looking like (which is undesired)

```
{
  desc: 'foo',
  summary: 'bar',
  ts: 00000000,
  status:'success',
  data: [{
    id: '37r878',
    desc: 'foo',
    summary: 'bar',
    ts: 00000000,
    status: 'open'
  }],
  message: null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Model.parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) when you want to alter how Backbone interprets what your server returns. Something like

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function (resp) {
        return resp.data[0];
    }
});
```

Comment: The question was posted 7 hours ago... how come you find this question and write an answer the exact moment I was writing an answer..! I started following Backbone since it's a low traffic tag compared to jQuery and stuff.. isn't it 6AM in paris? come on! :)

Comment: Sorry about my insomnia:)